# Incorrect Input/Doc URL Error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the following code which connects to a oracle database via soap, creates an XML Blob and returns it to the screen.

I am receiving the following error, and cannot figure out why.

```
array(3) {
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(11) "soap:Client"
  ["faultstring"]=>
  string(22) "Error processing input"
  ["detail"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["OracleErrors"]=>
    string(39) "
        Incorrect Input Doc/URL
      "
  }
}
```

I am using the following function to call a stored procedure.

```
function getUsersData(){

    $xmlfunc    = 'GETUSERS';
    $pkg            = 'JSON_EXPORTS';
    $inparam    = array("SESSIONHASH-VARCHAR2-IN" => $_SESSION['sessionhash']);

    $outparam = array("USERSDATA-XMLTYPE-OUT");

    $oradb = oradb::getconnection();
    $oradb->newxml($xmlfunc,$pkg,$inparam,$outparam);

    $result = $oradb->getxml(false,false,false,true);

    print_r($result);

}
```

This is the stored procedure I am calling:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY vivouser.json_exports IS
 -- @Oracle bexV2

  PROCEDURE getusers(sessionhash  IN VARCHAR2,
                     usersdata    OUT XMLTYPE)
  IS
    p_companyid     number;
    p_storegroupid  number;
    p_userid        number;
  BEGIN

  bexcore.checksessionid(sessionhash, p_companyid, p_storegroupid, p_userid);

  usersdata := bexcore.CreateXMLData(
    'select userid, 
        tbu.companyid, 
        tbu.firstname, 
        tbu.middlename, 
        tbu.lastname, 
        tbu.gender, 
        tbu.payrollnumber, 
        tbu.ismanager, 
        tpt.description, 
        tpt.wagerate 
    from tbuser tbu
        left join tbposition tbp using (USERID)
        left join tbpositiontype tpt using (POSITIONTYPEID);'
    );

  END getusers;

END json_exports;
```

Also, please note: $_SESSION['sessionhash'] is proven to be a logical hash value. All other soap calls using this format function as expected. Bexcore.checksessionid is also proven to be valid, and not the cause of this error, as is bexcore.createXmlData (they are each used in thousands of other cases in the same way and run as expected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having, was that the user accessing the database did not have permissions set to allow calling the requested packages.

use

`grant all on <packagename> to <user>;`

to solve this problem.